# how to use clip-path to clip pagewrapper ( From upper-left corner to lower-right corner ) to achieve a page transition animated

Tags: javascript, css

i saw this animated on this [website](https://www.koenigsegg.com/) , click the top-right button to active this animate

i try to use @keyframes to achieve this animated,but it did not work perfectly (it show Stuck during this animted run).
below is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(18, 16, 16, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: 1s flush ease;
}

@keyframes flush {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    ;
  }
  20% {
    clip-path: polygon(68% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 28%);
  }
  40% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 27%, 100% 34%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 56%);
  }
  60% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 63%, 100% 78%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 18% 100%);
  }
  80% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 84%, 100% 97%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 52% 100%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet doing something similar to the site you shared.

It only relies on transition and not animations, some javascript is inserted to trigger the transition and handle the state of the page properly :)

```js
let state = 'top'
const content = document.getElementById("content")

function onTransitionEnd() {
  if (state === 'bot') {
    onClick();
  }
}
function onClick() {  
  content.classList.remove("top");
  content.classList.remove("mid");
  content.classList.remove("bot");
  switch (state) {
    case 'top': {
      state = 'mid';
      content.classList.add("mid");
      break;
    }
    case 'mid': {
      state = 'bot';
      content.classList.add("bot");
      break;
    }
    case 'bot': {
      state = 'top';
      content.classList.add("top");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.base {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("https://static.lpnt.fr/images/2017/01/27/6846655-6846643-g-jpg_4053869_1000x667.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.animated {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;      
}
.animated-border {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.animated-background {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130%;
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translateY(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.animated-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.content.top .animated-background {
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translateY(-120%);
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
.content.bot .animated-background {
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translateY(120%);
}

.content.top .animated-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
.content.mid .animated-content {

}
.content.bot .animated-content {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content top">
  
  <div class="fixed">
    <strong>Super App</strong>
    <button onclick="onClick()">
      X
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="base">
  </div>
  
  <div id="animated" class="animated" ontransitionend="onTransitionEnd()" >
    <div class="animated-background"></div>
    <div class="animated-content">
      Animated
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```